# Failed to load module `App` in AppTests XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, xctest, capacitor

So I added a XCTest UnitTest folder in xcode (12.4) and tried to import my App to test some components of it.

However for seem reason I get the error

```
Failed to load module `App`
```

When I try to import my App

```
@testable import App
```

the App is called `App` as it is a generated PWA using Capacitor. I'm building for iOS.

I've looked all over this forum and StackOverflow but I have yet to see anyone with the same issue.

What am I missing here?
Anyone any ideas?

Thanks